# In a certain code language if CONFIDENCE is coded as FGPEGEQPHK then how will PERFECTION be coded in the same language

Tags: cipher

A certain code enciphers `CONFIDENCE` as `FGPEGEQPHK`. What will it do to `PERFECTION`?

Comment: I see you're new here, hello! For the next time I'd leave out the "please give the answer asap." But that's just a minor gripe, I hope you enjoy the puzzling stack exchange!

Comment: "IMO question paper"? IMO question papers are not like this. Or does IMO not stand for what I think it stands for?

Comment: Is this a question from an ongoing competition? Or "paper", since you phrase it that way?

Comment: (I edited the question to remove the "please answer as quickly as possible" stuff.)

Comment: Niharika, Hugh is right: PSE is not meant to be a service for helping people do well in competitions using other people's effort. If that's what you were intending here ... well, unfortunately you've got your answer, but please don't do it again.

Answer (score 7):

I think it would be written as:

> EVKQPRGTHG

Because:

> Counting the letters that make up the word and comparing it to the translation's count reveals they have the same amount of letters and also the same amount of different letters. It looked to be translated by a rot2 and that seemed to make: Confidence -> EQPHKFGPEG which looked really similar except the two halves are switched. So it becomes: EQPHKFGPEG -> EQPHK FGPEG -> FGPEGEQPHK 
>  So if you do the same procedure with PERFECTION, you get the following: PERFECTION -> rot2 -> RGTHGEVKQP -> switch halves -> EVKQPRGTHG 
>  All in all, the answer is EVKQPRGTHG